# Adding an Item in Chronological Order

Tags: jquery, list, html-lists

I'm creating a workout logger. The adding is working just fine, but I'd also like to list them in chronological order.

```
$('#logIt').click( function() {
    var date = new Date($('#workoutDate').val());
    var activity = $('#activity').val();

    $('.history').prepend('<li title="' + date + '">'
            + activity
        + '</li>');
    $('#logger')[0].reset();

    return false;

});
```

Firstly, I figure I need to get the date from the existing li's (I figured putting this in the title would be simplest since I don't want to display this data, but open to alternatives) to compare with the new date, but I can't even figure that out. I appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction.

**UPDATE**

Does `.each` work with dynamically generated content? All my content is dynamic and it seems like this is only able to add items to the bottom of the list. I've been modifying and experimenting for hours, but I don't feel like I'm any closer to the solution.

```
$('#logIt').click( function() {
    var date = new Date($('#workoutDate').val());

    if($('.history').is(':empty')){
        $('.history').append('<li data-date="' + date + '">'
            + date
        + '</li>');
        return false;
    }

    $('.history li').each(function() {
        var logged_date = new Date($(this).attr('data-date'));

        if(date <= logged_date){
            var position = $(this).index()-1;
            $('.history li').eq(position).after('<li data-date="' + date + '">'
                + date
            + '</li>');
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

Thank you again for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I've come up with.

```
$(document).ready( function() {     

    $("#workoutDate").datepicker();
    $("#workoutDate").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
    $("#workoutDate-btn").click( function(){
        if ( $("#workoutDate").datepicker("widget").is(":visible") ) {
            $("#workoutDate").datepicker("hide");
        } else {
            $("#workoutDate").datepicker("show");
        }
    });

    // this adds an item to a user's history
    $('#logIt').click( function() {
        var date = new Date($('#workoutDate').val());

        $('.history').append('<li data-date="' + date + '">'
            + date
        + '</li>');

        sortDates();
        return false;
    });

});

function sortDates() {
    var $dateArray = $('.history li');

    $dateArray.sort(function(a,b){
        var a = new Date( $(a).text() );
        var b = new Date( $(b).text() );

        if ( a < b ){
            return -1;
        }
        if ( a > b ){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    $('.history').html($dateArray);
    $dateArray.sort(function(a,b){
        return new Date( $(a).text() ) < new Date( $(b).text() );
    });

    $('.history').html($dateArray);
}
```

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a `data-` attribute. E.g.,

```
$('.history').prepend('<li data-date="' + date + '">' + activity + '</li>');
```

For more info, see [HTML data-* Attributes on W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

Comment: I like that better than using title. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JSfiddle i've created for you: http://jsfiddle.net/3aC8V/1/
it's not complete but it's an idea on how to modify lists dynamically, and compare dates.
It's a good start:

### Javascript

```
     $('#custom_date').click(function() {

        var custom_date =  $('#user_input').val();   
        //make sure the list is growing
        console.log($('.history li').children().length);

        $('.history li').each(function() {

        var logged_date = $(this).find('input').attr('title');
          if (new Date(custom_date) <= new Date(logged_date)) 
          {

              var position = $(this).index()-1;
              console.log(custom_date+'is
              less than'+logged_date+'position is:'+position);   

             $('.schedule ul li').eq(position).after('<li><input title="' + 
custom_date + '" value = "'+custom_date+'"></input></li>');
                return false;
          }


        });    

        });


        $('#current_date').click( function() {

        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd;} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm;} 
        today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
        console.log(today);


            $('.history li').each(function() {

            var logged_date = $(this).find('input').attr('title');
             if (new Date(logged_date)> new Date(today)) {

            //get index of element
            var position = $(this).index()-1;

             $('.history li').eq(position).after('<li>
             <input title="' + today + '" value = "'+today+'">
              </input></li>');
                return false;
            }

            });



        });
```

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing this. _$(this).attr('title').val();_ isn't doing anything. In fact, the script seems to completely fall apart here. Is this unavailable in 1.8.3?

Comment: @BenRinehart The code was just an idea i've updated my post for a  more in-depth solution to your problem you can modify it further.